# Roller blinds for bay window with little flat area around

Tags: windows, blinds

I live in a tenement flat meaning I have a beautiful bay window made up of 3 separate windows. However, when I started looking for roller blinds I realised there is probably not enough flat area around the window to fit them. Recess blinds aren’t an option either because I have sash windows. Has any one had this problem before and is there a way to deal with it?[image: photo of the angled surrounding area]

Comment: How/why does a sash preclude a recess blind?

Comment: Maybe ask for a free quote from a blind company and see what solution they have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide some photos with more context?